# Fill a Form in the WebBrouser control using InvokeScript

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I tried to fill a form in WebBrowser using InvokeScript. This code worked:

```
WebBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('name').value = 'anyword'")
```

But when I tried to reference a textbox in the script, it didn't work:

```
WebBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('name').value = textBox1.text")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", 
                         "document.getElementById('name').value = '" 
                         + textBox1.text + "'")
```